# Resonance in an open pipe with an angled non-squared end

Tags: acoustics, resonance

An open pipe (organ pipe) has a narrow, high Q resonance.
Is there any research out there for the effect on Q at different angles of end cut?
If not I am going to get a carpet tube, a speaker and a saw ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The organ pipe's Q will indeed decrease. Although I have never seen an equation which expresses this, a simple estimate can be made as follows:

The slanted end joins the tube at two places, where the tube length is different. Calculate the resonances corresponding to those two different "effective" tube lengths; these will furnish upper and lower bounds for the spread in resonances the tube will support.

Please report back when your experiments are completed so you can share the results!